# how to groupTuple channels to a sorted tuple in nextflow

Tags: nextflow

I have ch_lf, ch_hb and ch_stat2. they have similar patterns. ch_lf is like:

```
[id1, linkedfrag.id1.chr1]
[id1, linkedfrag.id1.chr2]
...
```

I want to get ch_phase, which is like:

```
[id1, [linkedfrag.id1.chr1,linkedfrag.id1.chr2,...], [hb_id1_chr1,hb_id2_chr2...], [stat2_id1_chr1,stat2_id1_chr2,...]]
[id2,...]
```

I did the following:

```
ch_lf.groupTuple().set {ch_lfs}
ch_hb.groupTuple().set {ch_hbs}
ch_stat2.groupTuple().set {ch_stat2s}

ch_phase = ch_lfs.concat(ch_hbs, ch_hetsnpvcfs).groupTuple()
  .map {id, files -> tuple(id, files[0], files[1], files[2], files[3])} //how to do this smarter
```

so ch_lfs is like:

```
[id1, [linkedfrag.id1.chr1, linkedfrag.id1.chr2,...]]
[id2,...]
```

I have two problems:

1. from ch_lf, ch_hb and ch_stat2 to ch_phase, is there a better way to achieve this? I thought of using join, but seems it can only join two (I have ch_lfs, ch_hbs and ch_stat2s)
2. how to sort the order of the elements in the output channel of groupTuple, for example, numeric order of the chromosome

Comment: The answer to 'how to do this smarter' would be to use the spread operator `.map {id, files -> tuple( it, *files ) }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sort` parameter will let you supply a custom sorting criteria using a [Closure](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/script.html#script-closure) or [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) object. Here's one way to sort the files based on the chromosome suffix in the filenames. It sorts by chromosome number then sex chromosome, and falls back to sorting based on the chromosome or contig name (i.e. if the chromosome is not a number or sex chromosome). Finally, it falls back to using the filenames if all else fails:

```
def sort_filenames = { delimiter ->
    { file1, file2 ->

        def suffix1 = file1.name.split(delimiter, 3).last()
        def suffix2 = file2.name.split(delimiter, 3).last()

        def chrom1 = suffix1.startsWith('chr') ? suffix1.substring(3) : suffix1
        def chrom2 = suffix2.startsWith('chr') ? suffix2.substring(3) : suffix2

        // autosomes
        def num1 = chrom1.isInteger() ? chrom1 as int : null
        def num2 = chrom2.isInteger() ? chrom2 as int : null

        // allosomes
        def sex1 = chrom1 in ['X', 'Y'] ? chrom1 : null
        def sex2 = chrom2 in ['X', 'Y'] ? chrom2 : null

        // remaining
        def rem1 = chrom1 ==~ /[^_]+/ ? chrom1 : null
        def rem2 = chrom2 ==~ /[^_]+/ ? chrom2 : null

        def cmp_num = num1 && num2 ? num1 <=> num2 : num1 ? -1 : num2 ? 1 : null
        def cmp_sex = sex1 && sex2 ? sex1 <=> sex2 : sex1 ? -1 : sex2 ? 1 : null
        def cmp_rem = rem1 && rem2 ? rem1 <=> rem2 : rem1 ? -1 : rem2 ? 1 : null

        def cmp_result = cmp_num ?: cmp_sex ?: cmp_rem ?: null

        cmp_result ?: suffix1 <=> suffix2 ?: file1 <=> file2
    }
}
```

You can also chain multiple [join](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#join) operators to get the desired result:

```
workflow {

    ...

    ch_lfs = ch_lf.groupTuple( sort: sort_filenames('\\.') )
    ch_hbs = ch_hb.groupTuple( sort: sort_filenames('_') )
    ch_s2s = ch_s2.groupTuple( sort: sort_filenames('_') )

    ch_phase = ch_lfs.join( ch_hbs ).join( ch_s2s )

    ch_phase.view()
}
```

Note that the `size` parameter should be supplied when using the [`groupTuple`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#grouptuple) operator so that the collected tuples can be sent downstream as soon as possible.